# Having problem translating these two sentences

Tags: sentence-translation, translation-explanation

I had trouble understanding a two-part translation exercise.
First part:

> *Cui Galba agricola fabulam novam narrat?*
>   Answer: To whom does Galba, the farmer, tell the new story?

How was I supposed to guess that "Galba" and "the farmer" were supposed to be written the way that they are? I wrote this:

> To whom does the farmer Galba tell a new story?

My guess is that the first translation makes the English more ok then the second.

For the second part of sentence :

> *Filiabus dominae clarae fabulam novam narrat.*
>   Answer: He tells the new story to the daughters of the famous lady.

The part that got me stuck is *filiabus* I have no idea where the *-bus* part comes from since I don't remember ever seeing something like this at this point. Any explanation on this part would be helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the first part: the two are equivalent. I like "the farmer Galba" better, but either is correct; it's just a matter of style.

For the second part: this is one of the few really weird things in the first declension.

As you know, the usual dative and ablative plural ending is *-īs* in the first declension. This would give the form *fīliīs*. But *-īs* is also the dative/ablative plural ending in the **second** declension. So *fīliīs* could also be a form of *fīlius*.

So in this one specific circumstance—when a first-declension noun has the same stem as a second-declension noun—the dative and ablative plural ending becomes *-ābus* instead. So you see *fīliābus*, *deābus*, and a very few others that I can't think of right now.

Comment: On the case ending -abus rather than -ī for first-declension nouns in the dative and ablative plural declensions, see (for example) Hiley, *The Elements of Latin Grammar*, p. [6](https://books.google.com/books?id=LXkBAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA6#v=onepage&q&f=true), §4.